# Cannot kill container: foo: Container foo is not running

Tags: command-line, virtualization, docker, awk, container

Perhaps `kill` is incorrect terminology, or I'm at least using it incorrectly.

How do I destroy docker containers?  Put them in the trash.  Delete.  Remove.  Erase.

```
docker container kill $(docker ps -a -q  | awk '{print $1}')
```

doesn't quite work:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 06e44d24ba8d: Container 06e44d24ba8d3df83e10a1829f04755cb9053faa68ab3dabccd10c3ee1c80322 is not running
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 22539a069e3b: Container 22539a069e3b8bbbd27b062603a7667857ac1a5e64242004fe7b72411a9cdbca is not running
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 1f7cf43ab398: Container 1f7cf43ab398e6e18416f69fc947b49d9792b1932a4b157f0514f9f6638ca185 is not running
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 7fc8c24ccabe: Container 7fc8c24ccabef04215df9ba7b8c171df6b963942e6e90c92a462cc0ab9d5dcb0 is not running
```

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/51015597/4531180

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`docker kill` will not *destroy* containers, it will just *kill* (stop) the **running** containers. But `docker ps -a` will show also the non-running containers, so you get an error for all these non-running containers.

Leave out the `-a` to kill only all running containers:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

Use [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) instead of `docker kill` if you want the processes to first try to terminate themselves (`SIGTERM`) instead of killing directly (`SIGKILL`).

Or use [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) to remove (destroy) containers:

```
docker rm --force $(docker ps -a -q)
```

`--force` or `-f` is needed to also rm running containers.

**Note:**
this will remove **all** containers.

Use [`docker container prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/) to remove all stopped containers.

---

Please read the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/docker/) or run `docker help` to get more information about all the commands.

Comment: what's the distinction then between `docker kill` and `docker stop` in relation to your answer?  (Yes, I'll RTFM -- but thanks for the answer.)

Comment: The difference is: [`stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/): *The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL.* and for [`kill`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/): *The main process inside the container is sent SIGKILL*